# $\int_0^x\sin^a(t)\cos^b(t)dt=$?

Tags: integration, special-functions

I just thought of this integral:
$$I(a,b,x)=\int_0^x\sin^a(t)\cos^b(t)dt$$
I know that $$I(a,b,\pi/2)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{a+1}2)\Gamma(\frac{b+1}2)}{2\Gamma(\frac{a+b}2+1)}$$
And I know how to reach this result myself, but I do not know how to even start on evaluating $I(a,b,x)$, so that's why I have no attempts to show you.

Is there any way to find a general form for $I(a,b,x)$ (potentially in terms of special functions)?

Comment: Hi, the integral I(a, b, x) $ is called incomplete beta function, unfortunately there is nothing to do about it, maybe expand into series but it would not be a closed form anymore so one just sticks with incomplete beta function.

Comment: @Dahaka oh. Okay, thank you.

Comment: Maybe those links are helpful for you: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function. To get to the same integral written there you can just use the same approach as you did here:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973000/515527

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but this post shows a special value of incomplete beta functiom. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885580/finding-an-elementary-evaluation-of-b-1-2a-1-a